# content tags for android accessibility for actionscript

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, adobe-animate

I am developing an app in animate with ActionScript 3. When I create the **aab** file and upload it to the **Google Play console** it gives me a warning that there are no content tags for accessibility. Apparently I have to create them with `android:contentDescription` (I don't know what this language is: Java?).

I'm looking for information on the internet about this (accessibility tags for android and as3) and I can't find anything. I ask if someone can guide me or give me clues on how to continue searching.

**Question:**
How can I implement these tags in my application using ActionScript 3 (Adobe Animate)?

Comment: I added the `Android` tag. Maybe some Android specialist can explain the _"contentDescription"_ part for you to then implement same result via an AS3/Adobe process.

Comment: Muchas gracias.